# Assign a integer identifier to strings in a 1-d array

Tags: arrays, string, list, numpy, int

need code that inputs array of strings & outputs list of integers that represent the string numerically

ex.

```
input: array( 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c')

output: [0, 1, 0, 2, 2]
```

need most efficient way bc there are **10000 strings**; using **numpy arrays**

Comment: Show your code effort

Answer (score 0):

```
_, ids = np.unique(input, return_inverse=True)
```

Comment: Some commentary would go a long way toward making this a useful answer.